# Spring Session - properly setup when configuring a HeaderHttpSessionStrategy

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-session

I'm in trouble trying to configure a scenario where I want that the set of Spring Security / Spring Session propagate a Header instead of a Cookie when using HttpSession. Basically, my configuration is something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisHttpSessionTimeoutConfiguration {

    // ... some code here

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy(){
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }
}
```

Beside that, I'm also using OAuth2 to manage the authentication and my final Spring boot looks like:

```
// some annotations such as @EnableDiscoveryClient / @EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(RedisHttpSessionTimeoutConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    public static class OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**")
              .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(getCSRFTokenRepository())
            .and().addFilterAfter(createCSRFHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

        }

        private Filter createCSRFHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, RequiredCookieAndHeaders.CSRF);
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie(RequiredCookieAndHeaders.CSRF, token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository getCSRFTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName(RequiredCookieAndHeaders.CSRF_ANGULAR_HEADER_NAME);

            return repository;
        }
//some more code
}
```

The situation that happens is that if I comment the config that return a bean with **return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();** my code works and I'm able to authenticate successfully. However, if I keep this code, for some unknown reason (at least for me) I'm getting a *OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token*

Debugging both code (with and without HeaderHttpSession enabled) I realize that the problem occurs when on this method org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getParametersForTokenRequest(...) the code try to recover a preservedState (request.getPreservedState()) - it results in null with Header set.

Does someone have a clue?

**Edited from here**

---

Just to complement my description - what the flow of my OAuth is: redirect towards an OpenAM endpoint where I have an authorize endpoint. Once everything is ok, this authorize will redirect to /login. It is, I'm not controlling what this OpenAM server propagate.  Just more info, my application.yml:

```
...

security:
  oauth2:
    sso:
      loginPath: /login

    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://${authserver.hostname}:${authserver.port}/${authserver.contextPath}/oauth2/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://${authserver.hostname}:${authserver.port}/${authserver.contextPath}/oauth2/authorize
      clientId: poc-x
      clientSecret: poc-x-pass
      clientAuthenticationScheme: header
      scope: api
...
```

---

P.S.: Sorry if the question sounds confusing. Despite the fact that English is not my 1st language, this problem was hard to explain.

Comment: You also have to send the header back to the server, without it you will not have a session. So you have to add some code on the client side as well to populate the session header.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, I've just edited my question to add some comments - as there are a set of redirects, I'm struggling about how to send the header back to server, as you mentioned. Thanks